# How to get all elements from a List

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I add each day of the current month to a list in a specific format.

```
public static List<string> GetMonthDays()
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, 1);
    int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(startTime.Year, startTime.Month);
    List<string> currentMonth = new List<string>();
    //string[] currentMonth = new string[daysInMonth];
    for (int i = 0; i < daysInMonth; ++i) {

        DateTime currentDate = startOfMonth.AddDays(i);
        currentMonth.Add(currentDate.ToString("dddd - dd.MM.yy", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));              
    }
    return currentMonth;
}
```

I am currently calling the method as follows, but I can only call a single index. How can I retrieve all the elements from the list?

```
var monthCurrent = new List<string> { GetMonthDays()[0] };
ws.Cells["A4:A34"].LoadFromArrays(new List<string[]>(new[] { monthCurrent.ToArray() }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
ws.Cells["A4:A34"].LoadFromArrays(GetMonthDays().ToArray());
```

Edit: I see, `LoadFromArrays` takes multiple. Then use [`LoadFromCollection`](https://documentation.help/OfficeOpenXML/1724eb5c-f040-e69f-a87f-aebe2243cb3a.htm):

```
ws.Cells["A4:A34"].LoadFromCollection(GetMonthDays());
```

Comment: `ws.Cells["A4:A34"].LoadFromArrays(new List<string[]>(new[] { GetMonthDays().ToArray() }));` for me. Thx for the hint.

Comment: @Marco: Ok i see, it takes multiple. Why don't you use `LoadFromCollection` then? So `s.Cells["A4:A34"].LoadFromCollection(GetMonthDays());`

Comment: You are right, awesome.